# How to handle foriegn key in djanog user model, When I do not want admin user to have a foreign key?

Tags: django, django-models

My custom user model has forigen key "info"
I want each user to have an acount in my app with some infomration(linked to the info model)
But the admin user has no such account it only manages the user information
I do not want admin user to have a foriegn key

So if I set the defalut=null I get "NOT NULL constraint failed: app_myuser.info_id"
Or if i set defualt=0 I get FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
(On using the command python mange.py createsuperuser)

Please tell me the right way to handle this situation

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser


class info(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        age = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,username ,key,password=None):
         
        user = self.model(username=username)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        user.info  = key
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password=None):
      
        user = self.model(username=username)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    info = models.ForeignKey(info, on_delete=models.CASCADE ,default=None)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

Comment: You need to add the parameter `null=True` if you want the field to be nullable

Comment: @schwartz721 thanks so much.  but is this good practice to add null fields in foregin key coloumn?

Comment: It always depends on the case. In general, there's no taboo against nullable foreign keys. In your particular case where every user should have the `info` foreign key with the exception of the admin user, you might consider giving the admin user `info` (name=admin) so you can enforce `info` as non-nullable at the database level, or you can enforce non-nullable at the code level in the Manager class when `is_admin` is False.